# $watch not working the second time when a string is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple input validation function. The input will be validated every time the user hits `submit`. Somehow $watch only works for the first time when the input is invalid, and won't work for the second time and following times.

The code is below.

```
<form ng-submit="validateInput(input)">
  <input ng-model="input.first">
  <input ng-model="input.second">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

function validateInput(input) {
  $scope.errorMessage = ""; //reset errorMessage to "" for every new submission.
  if (condition) {
    //http call
  } else {
    $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid input".
  }
}

app.directive('showError', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(_scope, _element) {
      _scope.$watch('errorMessage', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          $(_element).find("#errorMessage").html(newVal);
          $(_element).slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
        }
      });

      $(_element).find(".hide-message").on("click", function() {
        $(_element).slideUp();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The `showError` directive is an attribute of a panel in the page. When an error message needs to be shown, the panel will slide down from the top of the page showing the error message and then slide up after 3 seconds.

The first time when `conditon==false`, $watch will be triggered. But the second time (and following times), $watch will not be triggered.

I have used `console.log($scope.errorMessage)` to make sure that for every submission, `errorMessage` will first be set to `""`, then `"Invalid input"`. But the panel will just slide down for the first time, not for the following times.

The weird thing is: It always works if I just pass inputs to back end for validation and get back `errorMessage` from back end.

(Thanks for all the help. The brief solution: $watch will work if the $digest cycle is triggered. $http call will trigger the $digest cycle. In this case, $digest cycle is not triggered and I have to trigger it manually using $apply or $timeout.)

Comment: can you post your HTML?

Comment: @Dan Hi Dan. I just added the brief html code.

Comment: So you set errorMessage to a value, then you set it to the same value over and over again? It doesn't trigger the watch because nothing changed, it's still "Invalid input".

Comment: @hassassin Every time the user hits submit, errorMessage will be set to "".

Comment: where are your 'showError' directive in the HTML??

Comment: You don't need showError directive at all. Just remove it and use ngShow/ngIf.

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia The directive is a panel in the page. When an error message needs to be shown, the panel will slide down from the top of the page and then slide up after 3 seconds.

Comment: @dfsq I cannot remove it. Someone else wrote it for our website project. It works fine for other invalid input cases except this one.

Comment: Right, but it only matters what the value of errorMessage is during a digest cycle, if you set it to "" then back to the same value, it's like you did nothing.

Comment: @hassassin The weird thing is: It always works if I just pass inputs to back end for validation and get back errorMessage from back end, So you may be right that if I am doing this validation in front end, i am like doing nothing because the digest cycle detects no change at all. Do you have any idea of fixing this?

Comment: check this http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/ZQJvyY ... it looks like you've been doing?

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia Thanks! Now I know that I can use $timeout to trigger the digest manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting errorMessage from "Invalid input" to "" and back to "Invalid input" within a single `$digest` loop, so the `$watch` never triggers (because as far as it knows the value never changed).

A lazy but viable solution would be to simply delay setting errorMessage back to "Invalid input" by a tick, so the `$watch` has time to notice something changed:

```
function validateInput(input) {
    $scope.errorMessage = ""; //reset errorMessage to "" for every new submission.
    if (condition) {
        //http call
    } else {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid input";
        });
    });
}
```

(A better solution would probably be to use an error handler that can be invoked directly instead of by `$watch`ing a variable, but it sounds like the ship's sailed on that particular design choice...)

Comment: Thanks. I was just realizing that I need to trigger the $digest manually, then I saw your solution.

Comment: You could manually trigger the digest using `scope.$apply()` but in this case it's probably easier to just wait for the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can fix this by either manually triggering the digest or waiting for the next one. But not sure why you are building your own form validation in Angular. Angular provides a great implementation for handling form (validation etc) out of the box.

View:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
  Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="formDate.name" name="name" required="" />
  <br />
  <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.name.$touched" custom-error>
    <div ng-show="form.name.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
    <div ng-show="form.name.$error.customError">For some reason our name needs to be a number.</div>
  </div>

  Age:
  <input type="number" ng-model="formDate.age" name="age" required="" />
  <br />
  <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.name.$touched">
    <div ng-show="form.age.$error.required">Tell us your age.</div>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {
       name: '',
       age: '' 
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        //http call accessin form data through our $scope model
    }
});
```

Here angular will handle hiding or showing the error messages and the form errors. Angular forms create a form controller and through this controller you can access each form element and its errors (i.e. form.name.$required). Regular validation like max, min, length, required etc comes out of the box but it becomes really strong when combined with the ability to write custom validation (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Custom validation directive

```
.directive('customError', function() {
        var CUSTOM_ERROR_REGEXP = /^\d+$/;
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$validators.customError = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                // consider empty models to be valid
                return true;
                }

                if (CUSTOM_ERROR_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                // it is valid
                return true;
                }

                // it is invalid
                return false;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To create your own checks is best used reusable components, for example directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).

Look at the example of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/703qxbcg/).

```
<form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input ng-model="password" required />
  <br>
   <label>Confirm password</label>
  <input ng-model="confirmPassword" required />
  <div use-form-error="isSame" use-error-expression="password && confirmPassword && password!=confirmPassword" ng-show="ExampleForm.$error.isSame">Passwords Do Not Match!</div>
</form>
```